# SpringBootTest: how to know when boot application is done

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, qpid

Spring boot integration test looks like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application)
class IntegrationTest {

  static QpidRunner qpidRunner

  @BeforeClass
  static void init() {
    qpidRunner = new QpidRunner()
    qpidRunner.start()
  }

  @AfterClass
  static void tearDown() {
    qpidRunner.stop()
  }

}
```

So, Qpid instance is run before and teared down after all tests. I want to know is there a way to check whether spring boot application is still running before calling `qpidRunner.stop()`. I want to stop Qpid only when I'm sure that spring app has finished its stopping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account that `ConfigurableWebApplicationContext` can be injected in a `SpringBootTest`, adding this lines to the code solved the problem

```
static ConfigurableWebApplicationContext context

@Autowired
void setContext(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext context) {
  AbstractDocsIntegrationTest.context = context
}

@AfterClass
static void tearDown() {
  context.stop()
  qpidRunner.stop()
}
```

Spring docs about [stop method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html#stop-java.lang.Runnable-)

> Stop this component, typically in a synchronous fashion, such that the
>   component is fully stopped upon return of this method.

JUnit `AfterClass` annotated method must be static, therefore `@Autowired` workaround with setContext method.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Boot integration test can configure an `ApplicationListener` which listens for [`ContextClosedEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-events). Define a nested `@TestConfiguration` class inside the test class to add beans to the application's primary configuration.

```
@TestConfiguration
static class MyConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> contextClosedEventListener() {
    return event -> qpidRunner.stop();
  }
}
```